# Excel VBA userform run-time error - Fill a value finding references on the same row

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, userform

I've run into another problem in my vba project, when i insert a value in my form, it searches where that number is on column 1 and returns the values from the same row on column 3 and 12 to the form. When i fill the form and press enter it shows this error:

> "Run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)':
> Could not set value property. Type mismatch."

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub txtdevolução_AfterUpdate()

Dim id As String, rowcount As Integer, foundcell As Range

id = txtdevolução.Value

    rowcount = thisworkbook.Sheets("retornos pendentes").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With thisworkbook.Worksheets("retornos pendentes").Range("A1:A" & rowcount)
        Set foundcell = .Find(what:=id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then
            txtclienteopl.Value = .Cells(foundcell.Row, 3)
            txtmatricula2.Value = .Cells(foundcell.Row, 12)
         Else
            txtclienteopl.Value = ""
            txtmatricula2.Value = ""
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

The line where the debugger stays is:

```
txtclienteopl.Value = .Cells(foundcell.Row, 3)
```

NOTE: The error appears on another computer with another user (my college), the file is on our company shared network disc.

Comment: What is the value in `.Cells(foundcell.Row, 3)`. You will get that error if for example the value is  #N/A

Comment: The value in that row is a text with no formulas, on row 12 could be text or number or even symbols like "-"

Comment: 3 and 12 are column, the information are text on the 3 and number/text on the 12

Comment: After the If Not found add a line `MsgBox TypeName(.Cells(foundcell.Row, 3).Value)`

Comment: It opens a msgbox with "string" in it

Comment: The better option would be to debug and add  `foundcell` and `.Cells(foundcell.Row, 3)` to the watch window. You could also use `foundcell.offset(0,3)`.

Comment: try using `txtclienteopl.Value = thisworkbook.Worksheets("retornos pendentes").Cells(foundcell.Row, 3)`

Comment: @Storax `foundcell.offset(0,3)` ? that would be column D, `foundcell.offset(0,2)`  perhaps

Comment: @CDP1802: Yes, right. Sorry! One off :-(

Comment: @k1dr0ck It returns the same error.

My college can work for 1h or 2h normaly, and then it gives that error. If he closes the workbook and opens again it doesn't give the error again.